# Text input typing is really slow when a big table is present

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom-events

I have a page with a pretty big table. Any text input on the same page responds really slowly to typing.

Anybody have any idea what would be the exact cause for this?

Occurs in Chrome (41~), but **not** in IE 10 or Firefox (30~).

Reducing the number of rows (to 20, for instance) makes the problem disappear.

Chrome's timeline shows ~500ms gaps between keypress/keydown events:

[image]

Could the long `ng-class`, `ng-click`, and other attributes be hogging Chrome's internal dom event handling?

Testable in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CGiEoWGsyZOsYFcw98ik).

(I've got angular all over the place in the original code, but the plunker is stripped of it.)

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the client does not want paging. We will probably implement virtual scrolling ourselves (we are using ng-table, which has no VS support), if there is no easier solution.

Comment: I'm seeing this in 2020, on an Angular2 app -- same scenario, an input with a large table. It only happens on Chrome. No Angular tags on the input. If I expand those arrows on the keypress events, it seems like something is making Chrome recalculate the layout after every one.